# Im making a bus booking system in Postgresql and got stuck on how to check if seats is available while booking

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I make some kind of statement checking if the seats isn't more than the number of seats that a bus actually have?

Right now I have the following tables:
Booking (route_id, mail, seats) --route_id foreign key to route(route_id) seats = number of seats to book

Bus (bus_id, seats, driver_ssc)

City (country, city_name, bus_stop, route_id)

Driver (name, driver_ssc, phone, adress)

Route (dep, arrival, dep_time, arrival_time, price, bus_id, route_id)

Traveler (fn, ln, phone, adress, mail, user_id)

Some information is just to fulfill the assignment I've got.

Please give suggestions on how to control the seats while booking. Ask if I need to explain anything that's not clear. Thank you!

Comment: how do you fix in the database that a seat has been booked? Now, you are able to identify only the number of seats for each route. It seems to me you need an additional table "booking" (user_id, route_id) then you will find a number of free seats easily.

Comment: I have a table named Booking (route_id, mail, seats) where mail identifies the user in this case. Can you give an example of how you would write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that 1 unique route_id has only 1 unique bus_id, right? 
If correct, This query may help you.

```sql
with booking_summary as (
    select 
        route_id, 
        sum(seats) as "total_book_seats"
    from
        booking
    group by route_id
)

select 
    route.route_id, 
    bus.bus_id, 
    booking_summary.total_book_seats, 
    bus.seats 
from
    booking_summary
        join route on booking_summary.route_id = route.route_id
        join bus on route.bus_id = bus.bus_id
where 
    booking_summary.total_book_seats > bus.seats
```

The concept is to calculate total booked seats into `booking_sumary` temp table. Then, join the temp table to other tables in order to get a number of bus seats.